# My screen is dark and I am unable to fix it through settings. My mouse however, is completely normal. How should I fix this? I am using ubuntu 20.04

Tags: screen

As mentioned in the question, my screen is now constantly dark with a bright mouse. Turning on the brightness makes the screen brighter, but it still is not as bright as it is normally.

Comment: Did it turn dark all of a sudden? Have you tried the on monitor controls? What have you tried in Ubuntu to fix it?

Comment: Are you using a laptop or a desktop?

Comment: I should have asked that :)